# Best way to use property files in Jetty

Tags: java, jetty, war

My application has a few property files for paths such as ws-endpoints, db-url etc. Some of these files are encrypted.

My WAR is running inside a Jetty container.

What is the best way to refer to these files? and where should they be placed in the jetty container?

currently I have references like this in jetty.xml:

```
<New id="app-config" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.EnvEntry">
    <Arg />
    <Arg>app-config</Arg>
    <Arg type="java.lang.String">file:<full-path></Arg>
    <Arg type="boolean">true</Arg>
</New>
```

it works, but I don't like these static references, is it any neat way that requires less config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen lots of folks drop those files into the $jetty.home/resources directory and pull them in via the classloader getResources() which is kinda neat :)

Comment: nice solution, I went for this one.